# How to count Yes/No responses and group them?

Tags: r

I have a survey from an excel file that looks like this

```
  party          question1         question2
1 Republican       Yes                No
2 Democrat         No                 Yes
3 Libertarian      No                 No
4 Green            No                 Yes
5 Republican       Yes                Yes
6 Constitution     Yes                No
7 Democrat         Yes                Yes
8 Democrat         No                 No
```

I want to have the number of Yes and Nos by party, so something like this

```
party           Yes   No
Republican       5    4
Democrat         1    3
Libertarian      5    6
Constitution     2    4
Green            4    1
```

Eventually I want to make a graph out of this. I have been looking all over and trying some stuff, the closest one has been

```
res1 <-as.data.frame(aggregate(question1, list(party), table))
```

which results in this

```
             Group.1 x.No x.Yes
1 constitution          2    12
2   democratic         21   267
3        green          4    21
4  libertarian         12    39
5   republican         27   155
```

which seems great except when I `View(res1)` it only shows as `"5 obs. of 2 variables"`. I can only see the Group1 column and the x.No column.
I need both Yes and No columns so I can graph them.

I also tried the `plyr` package but it's not working for me, no idea why.
I tried doing it in Rstudio via sqldf using some `CASE` functions but as much as I tried changing it around it would have an error.

As you can tell I am an absolute beginner, I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Based on the example, it is not counting 5 Yes, 4 No for Republican.  Is the expected output based on some other dat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `tidyverse` by converting to 'long' format with `gather`, the get the frequency with 'count' and `spread` it to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, key, val, question1:question2) %>%
   count(party, val) %>%
   spread(val, n)
```

---

Also, using `base R`

```
table(data.frame(df1[1], value = unlist(df1[-1])))
```

Comment: `table` solution, in particular, seems very direct. Suggest this variation to avoid the warning: `table(data.frame(party = df1[[1]], value = unlist(df1[-1])))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way with `xtabs`, after reformating the data.

```
long <- reshape2::melt(df1, id.vars = "party")
xtabs( ~ party + value, long)
#              value
#party          No Yes
#  Constitution  1   1
#  Democrat      3   3
#  Green         1   1
#  Libertarian   2   0
#  Republican    1   3
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
party          question1         question2
1 Republican       Yes                No
2 Democrat         No                 Yes
3 Libertarian      No                 No
4 Green            No                 Yes
5 Republican       Yes                Yes
6 Constitution     Yes                No
7 Democrat         Yes                Yes
8 Democrat         No                 No                  
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are solutions fixing the three approaches (sqldf, aggregate, plyr) attempted in the question.  We assume that the data frame input is `DF` as defined reproducibly in the Note at the end.

**1) sqldf** With sqldf:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select party, 
              sum(question1 = 'No') + sum(question2 = 'No') as No,
              sum(question1 = 'Yes') + sum(question2 = 'Yes') as Yes
       from DF
       group by party")
```

or if you have more than 2 questions dynamically create the SQL statement.  The `verbose=` argument will show the statement it actually sends to SQLite and you can omit it if you don't need that.

```
library(sqldf)

yes <- paste(sprintf("sum(%s = 'Yes')", names(DF)[-1]), collapse = " + ")
no <- paste(sprintf("sum(%s = 'No')", names(DF)[-1]), collapse = " + ")

fn$sqldf("select party, $no No, $yes Yes from DF group by party", verbose = TRUE)
```

**2) aggregate** To do it with aggregate try the following. The aggregate statement creates a two column data frame whose second column is a multicolumn matrix and the last statement, which is optional, converts that to an ordinary 3 column data frame.  This also works if there are more than 2 questions.

```
ag <- aggregate(list(Answer = 1:nrow(DF)), DF["party"], 
  function(i) c(No = sum(DF[i, -1] == 'No'), Yes = sum(DF[i, -1] == 'Yes')))
do.call("data.frame", ag)
```

or alternately:

```
yesNo <- data.frame(Yes = rowSums(DF[-1] == "Yes"), No = rowSums(DF[-1] == "No"))
aggregate(yesNo, DF[1], sum)
```

**3) plyr**  With the plyr package we can use this code:

```
library(plyr)

ddply(DF, .(party), summarize,
   No = sum(question1 == 'No') + sum(question2 == 'No'),
   Yes = sum(question1 == 'Yes') + sum(question2 == 'Yes'))
```

or if there can be more than 2 questions:

```
Count_No <- function(data) sum(data[, -1] == "No")
Count_Yes <- function(data) sum(data[, -1] == "Yes")
ddply(DF, .(party), c(No = Count_No, Yes = Count_Yes))
```

or alternately using `yesNo` from (2):

```
ddply(yesNo, .(party = DF$party), colSums)
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
  party          question1         question2
1 Republican       Yes                No
2 Democrat         No                 Yes
3 Libertarian      No                 No
4 Green            No                 Yes
5 Republican       Yes                Yes
6 Constitution     Yes                No
7 Democrat         Yes                Yes
8 Democrat         No                 No"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```